# How to find out the binded address and port of a running server progress written in python?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, sockets

Except from source code, I tried `$ netstat` and found nothing about the `server.py` app I was just running.

My app is here:

```
import socket
from server_const import const

def server(port=1060):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", port))
    print("The server is listening at {}".format(sock.getsockname()))
    while True:
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(const.MAX_BYTES.value)
        text = data.decode("utf-8")
        print("The client at {} says {!r}".format(address, text))
        text = "Your data was {} bytes long".format(len(data))
        data = text.encode("utf-8")
        sock.sendto(data, address)
```

I run my app in terminal and press `ctrl+z` to suspend the process, how can I find the binded address and port from my terminal?

Comment: looks like it's at `127.0.0.1:1060`

Comment: Try opening that address in a browser, and see what your program starts printing

Comment: @Patrick Haugh Yes ,I can see it from source code. But when I run my app in terminal and press `ctrl+z` to suspend the process, how can I find the binded address and port from my terminal?

Comment: When you suspend the process you stop the server, which is probably why you can't see it.  I would suggest using a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` to switch between terminal sessions so you can use a terminal while still running the server

Comment: @Patrick Haugh Thanks, I'll try it !

Comment: That's not true. This has nothing to do with suspending the process -- suspending it doesn't remove the socket. You need to use `netstat -a`. Without `-a`, `netstat` doesn't show listening sockets, only "connected" sockets.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on linux you can run the program as a background process to keep it from closing.

```
./server.py &
```

> You'll need to use a program like htop or top to terminate the program once it's running in the background. (of course there are several other ways)

Or alternatively you could open another terminal session.

Once you've got it running use this.

```
netstat -lnp | grep $(pgrep server.py)
```

netstat
-l: limits to listening processes,

-n: doesn't resolve names (since you said you wanted ip),

p: display programs (so we can search by name))

| pipe to combine commands

grep (search) by PI (Process ID)

$() variable, will be evaluated first

- pgrep server.py (searches for process id of named program)